# Query in document with inline default namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying/struggling to query the getCompanyListResponse-Tag(every tag above that one works fine with the namespacemanager and the "soap" prefix) within the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”> 
  <soap:Header /> 
  <soap:Body> 
    <getCompanyListResponse xmlns=”http://test.org/schema”>
      <company> 
        <id>12345</id> 
        <address> 
          <role>LOCATION</role>
        </adress>
      </company>
    </getCompanyListResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately I can't change any XML,because the XML is a response of a webservice, I'm not able to influence.
Sadly, adding the default namespace to the XMLNamespacemanager didn't work.
I didn't find any sufficient answer on how to use the local-name function .

```
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XPathDocument compDoc = new XPathDocument(responseStream);
XPathNavigator root =  compDoc.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager resolver = new XmlNamespaceManager(root.NameTable);
resolver.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
resolver.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://test.org/schema");
resolver.AddNamespace("null", "http://test.org/schema");
root.MoveToFirstChild();
XPathNavigator body = root.SelectSingleNode("[/local-name()='soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getCompanyListResponse']", resolver);
```

With the last line in the code right above I get the Exception: "the Expression must result in a node-set"(or close to that, since I use visual studio in German, is this my attempt of translation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a prefix in your path to address elements in a default namespace:

```
XPathDocument compDoc = new XPathDocument(responseStream);
XPathNavigator root =  compDoc.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager resolver = new XmlNamespaceManager(root.NameTable);
resolver.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
resolver.AddNamespace("ts", "http://test.org/schema");

XPathNavigator comp = root.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body//ts:company", resolver);

string id = comp.SelectSingleNode("ts:id").Value;
```

And your attempt with local-name() in a predicate without a step is also not going to work but not necessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to read an XML stream, but if I'm not understanding you I apologize. 
XmlReader seems to me its the right tool for the job.

XmlReader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream);
var xmlnsString = string.Empty;
string id;
while(reader.Read()){
if(reader.IsStartElement()){
    switch(reader.Name){
        case("getCompanyListResponse") : xmlnsString = reader.GetAttribute("xmlns"); 
        //list any name of a node you want to work on here
        case("id") : id = reader.ReadString();
        default: break;


    }

}    

}
```